# QFileDialog works only once after reboot (prints an error otherwise)

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

#### The problem

I use a QFileDialog. It worked very well and suddently my issue appeared.

After a reboot, the code given below works as expected. Then if I close the app and relaunch it, the modal window takes a long time to appear and never shows the folders.

After a while (5-10sec) a popup appears, which says something like: "[Error] The process dealing with the file protocol stoped unexpectedly"  (Mine is written in french)

Do anyone experienced this ?

#### EDIT: Last line of debug before the bug

When it's work (after a reboot) I launch the application and when I quit it, the debug reads

```
Cancelled FAM (Req 2) for "/media/Donnees/Videos_tmp"
Cancelled FAM (Req 1) for "/media/Donnees"
```

I think the problem is in these two lines.

#### System

ArchLinux 3.16.1

#### Code example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow l_mainWindow;
    l_mainWindow.show();
    QString l_folder = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    qDebug() << l_folder;
    return app.exec();
}
```

#### Console infos

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
QObject::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QString)
QObject::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QString)
"L'URL ne peut être listée
trash:/"
"L'URL ne peut être listée
trash:/"
Added Dir "/media/Donnees/Documents/Projets/" for "" ["KDirWatch-1"]
 Setup FAM (Req 1) for "/media/Donnees/Documents/Projets/"
Added Dir "/media/Donnees/Documents/Projets/subfold" for "" ["KDirWatch-1"]
 Setup FAM (Req 2) for "/media/Donnees/Documents/Projets/subfold"
Cancelled FAM (Req 1) for "/media/Donnees/Documents/Projets/"
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/olivier/.cache/ksycoca5"
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "KNotify/NotifyMethod" not found
Got configs "knotifications5/plasma_workspace.notifyrc" "plasma_workspace.notifyrc"
Got groups ()
Got notification " "messageCritical" " with actions: ""
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
```

Comment: Does problem exist if you write it like: `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Test", "/home");`? You can put any existing directory instead of "/home".

Comment: Yes. And it occures with getExistingDirectory as well. Therefor I think it can be a problem with the process used by the system (although I don't really know)

Comment: Does the problem reproduce in a fresh new project, where you only show the dialog, and do nothing else?

Comment: Good question I didn't think about it: but sadly **it does reproduce**

Comment: Sounds like a Qt or KDE bug?

Comment: Yes it can be but I don't know what's the process behind is...

Comment: Qt purge then reinstall didn't fix the problem

Comment: FAM is the file access monitor that's used to monitor changes to the files/directories in the real time, so that the dialog can keeps itself updated as the filesystem changes. If those are indeed error messages (and not merely informational messages), then they signify a failure of directory monitoring.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what can cause this and how to correct it N

Comment: @KubaOber: Indeed. The funny thing is, FAM is considered an obsolete technology these days. So either you've got a really old version of Qt installed, or some compatibility version. The last time I've seen `famd` being deployed was half a decade ago (or so it feels). These days we've got dnotify, inotify and such.

Comment: According to this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Monitoring_changes_on_local_files_and_directories  i don't need to install anything special ! I'm on ArchLinux, all updates done... I don't see how i can be outdated =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was it...

I had kf5 (=kde5) and kde4 which were in conflict. Since I removed the kf5 framework, the error disappeared.

Thanks guys for your time